# Почему не могу сделать push?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Я работаю с репозиторием нашим локальным, но теперь мне понадобилось добавить еще один репозиторий чтоб я мог делать `push and pull`

Я это сделал с помощью команды `git remote add myName myURL`

Вроде как все добавилось, но теперь когда я делаю `git push myName` то получаю вот такое сообщение

```
$ git push myName
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myURL.git/'
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: а там есть git:// интерфейс, а не https:// ?

Comment: @KoVadim Не совсем понял вопос

Comment: когда выполняли команду `git remote add myName myURL` то добавили ссылку на репозиторий в виде https://myurl. А хорошо бы добавить в виде git://myurl, но не все репы предоставляют так просто такой интерфейс.

Comment: @KoVadim так что мне сделать? Как проверить предоставляет этот репо интерфейс или нет? Нужно написать `git remote add myName git://'https://myurl` ?

Comment: так как Вы урл не пишете, то я не могу ответить на этот вопрос. Но обычно он есть. github/gitlab его предоставляют.

Comment: @KoVadim вот url https://alextimoshchenko@bitbucket.org/alextimoshchenko/el-al.git/

Comment: `ssh://user@name/site/path/to/repo.git`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, нужно проверить, есть ли доступ к репозиторию и правильно ли он настроен. (все делаем в консоле. Гуевые утилиты лучше деинсталлировать сразу, что бы не мешали).

Вначале выполняем команду

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.net
```

Ее вывод может быть таким (я звездочками затираю привтные данные)

> The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (104.192.143.1)' can't be established.
>
> RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:zz*******************jez9YXaGp1A.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Тут нужно явно ввести `yes` и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

В терминале будет такое

> Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.1' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.

После чего пробуем ещё раз.

Если пишет такое

> Permission denied (publickey).

это значит, что нет ключа. Его нужно добавить. На битбакете есть [подробная инструкция](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html).

Если все ок с ключем, то вывод должен быть такой

> logged in as <здесь будет Ваш никнейм на битбакете>.
>
> You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

Если такого ответа нет, дальше продолжать нет смысла, проверяем ключи, добавляем, гуглим.

Теперь возвращаемся к репозиторию и смотрим, что там прописано в локальной репе.

```
git remote -v
```

там будет что то такое

origin alextimoshchenko@bitbucket.org/alextimoshchenko/el-al.git (fetch)
origin alextimoshchenko@bitbucket.org/alextimoshchenko/el-al.git (push)

если нет - удаляем

```
git remote remove origin
```

(origin - это имя по умолчанию для удаленного репозитория. Оно было первым в предыдущем выводе. Если это не так - посмотрите и выберите правильное).

потом добавляем правильное

```
git remote add alextimoshchenko@bitbucket.org/alextimoshchenko/el-al.git
```

Все, должно работать.

Этот длинный путь можно сократить, если склонировать репозиторий по новому.

Возможные проблемы

- не хочет подключаться по ssh -T.

  проблемы с фаерволом или роутером/провайдером
- битбакет не принимает ключ.

  возможно, берется ключ, который сгенерирован путти (он в другом формате) или вместо публичного ключа берется приватный (распространенная ошибка). Или банально скопирован ключ криво.

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов, в адрес вашего репозитория могла закрасться ошибка/опечатка. Например, если взять любой из существующих на github репозиториев и намеренно допустить в нем ошибку, то вывод в консоль будет точно таким же как у вас.

Для того, чтобы проверить, что с remote или url remote все в порядке, можете воспользоваться

`git ls-remote remote_url.git`

Comment: опять же говорит что  Authentication failed

Comment: вы url используете такой же как в комментарии к вопросу? если да, попробуйте использовать url без логина. Или как вариант можете попробовать сделать все те же операции с репозиторием через SourceTree, он может дать более конкретное описание ошибки

Comment: > Или как вариант можете попробовать сделать все те же операции с репозиторием через SourceTree, он может дать более конкретное описание ошибки

**ага, конечно**